# How do I write dynamic php to file without code executing?

Tags: php

```
$configuration = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/settings/site.php';
if ($memtype == 'admin') {
    if (isset($_POST['sitename'])) {
        $handle = fopen($configuration,"wb") or die('Cannot open file:  '.$configuration);

        $data = "<?php $sitename = '".$_POST[sitename]."'; ?>";

        fwrite($handle, $data);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

When the above code runs what I expect to happen is for a file site.php to be created containing the following:

```
<?php $sitename = 'user defined variable'; ?>
```

instead what is happening is I am ending up with a file the contains:

```
<?php = 'user defined variable'; ?>
```

It appears the $sitename variable is actually parsed as a variable. As its inside quotes I would certainly not expect this to happen. I would expect it to be literally written to file as $sitename. So how exactly do I write a variable name to file without the variable being parsed?

Comment: PHP that writes PHP to a file and then runs it sounds like a super bad idea. What's the rationale behind this? Remember: [PHP double-quoted strings are interpolated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Use single quotes. Double quotes interpolate. Also, keep in mind that if you're writing this php to a directory accessible by your webserver, this scheme makes it possible to run arbitrary code on your server with a POST request.

Comment: @tadman - the rational is to create an installer saves variables to a file as opposed to connecting to a database and saving in a table. The reason, to avoid countless database calls. Imagine 50 0/1 settings for "is XYZ enabled". Each time a page is run it would have to check for those settings to see what is or isnt enabled. One could set them as session variables but that is not secure and a user could simply change the settings in their own sessions to enable site features. So its either a file of variables created during setup, or a database call to set variables on every page load.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, it  is actually parsed as a variable. What you can do is use single quote or escape special chars

Comment: Then save an [INI file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) instead of executable code. This is how super nasty exploits happen, *especially* since you take arbitrary user input and throw it into the file without question.

Comment: @tadman I certainly wouldn't say you are wrong, as I have only been coding a touch over a year.... but I am curious how a nasty exploit can happen and why you would call it an arbitrary user. Just trying to learn. I would think the if $memtype == 'admin' would ensure it is not an arbitrary user than can run the code - but only a user with a variable set making them admin? I am now reading up about using .INI files to do this. :)

Comment: Never assume that your admin accounts are invulnerable to compromise. Passwords get leaked all the time, and if they happen to re-use one on your site it's going to be bad times for you. It'll be a nightmare if that person can then write arbitrary PHP and do **whatver they want** with your site instead of being constrained by the existing functionality. INI files are just dumb data, you can't inject executable code in them. They're significantly safer. The worst a hijacked account can do then is flip switches that you've put in place.

Comment: You need to have a healthy amount of paranoia here and ensure that you're more than one simple mistake away from disaster. If you open-sourced this code, people would spot a mistake like this in seconds and could write a proof-of-concept exploit inside of minutes. A little CSRF to get a logged-in admin to click a link and your whole site just got owned, no password required.

Comment: Anyway, sorry to be such a killjoy here but innocent mistakes like this are punished severely by attackers. As annoying as it can be to fix it now, trust me, this is way better than waking up one day to find out your whole site has been compromised, is serving malware to your users, and your entire database is now floating around on BitTorrent.